# Order of Karaite prayers

Tags: tefilla, non-rabbinic-judaism

I was privileged to find a Karaite prayer book on the web, and it is the one edited by Nehemia Gordon in consultation with R’ Moshe Dabah based on the Avraham Firkovich Edition, originally published in Vilna in 1870.

It contains some of the most beautiful prayers I have ever seen, but my question is: What is the order in which the prayers are recited?
There appears to be 2 lots of week day evening and morning prayers.

Which is recited when?

Comment: Tim, welcome to Mi Yodeya! The moderators will give the full hospitality treatment, but I just wanted to inform you that very few of us here on Mi Yodeya are Karaite Jews who would be able to answer.

Comment: Hello Tim.  The prayers are beautiful.  Maybe you could inquire on the Karaite Korner web page then come back and answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: It would help if you posted the prayer book

Comment: I think this may be the one Tim Goodall was referring to http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Karaite-Prayerbook-Nehemia-Gordon-after-Avraham-Firkovich-Vilna-1871.pdf

Comment: Here is a copy of the Siddur: https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeuIblwdHNAhVLfRoKHad8AHgQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopensiddur.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F06%2FKaraite-Prayerbook-Nehemia-Gordon-after-Avraham-Firkovich-Vilna-1871.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHqqSjrkeBC7NUoQuIi9fjy7aocFg&sig2=a2fhgUTPa8L2lP29WD0hqQ

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know of one Karaite user here on Mi Yodeya and he's not a frequent visitor. Although questions about Karaite Judaism [are on-topic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/non-orthodox-opinions/472#472), there aren't a lot of people on here who could give you a good answer.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? I am a Karaite Jew.

Comment: PLEASE HELP US! @ABlueThread Even if the OP isn't interested in an answer anymore, I would love to learn more myself.

Comment: Putting a formal answer in the answers

Answer (score 2):

I am a Karaite Jew - raised in the Karaite tradition. A few notes:

1. I just did a class on the Karaite liturgy that you can check out here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrR6THBLhSA.
2. What he did in the siddur in question is print the evening siddur linearly (i.e. in the order in which the prayers are read, and there are various times when the day of the week matters. So on every (non-shabbat) night of the week you start on page 3 and when you get to page 6 you have to read the portion of your day. Then you continue (for all days of the week) on page 8. Then on page 9 again, you read the portion for your day of the week. Then you continue on page 12. Then finally on page 15, you read the final section that is related to the day. Then continue to the end of the prayer.
3. He did something similar with the morning prayer.

Does that answer your question?